# Perceptron outputs the same value for all inputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I am a newbie to neural networks. I coded a perceptron in Python 3.10 without using libraries. But I am facing an issue. It always returns either True for all the input data or False for all the input data. I am not sure why this happens.

**Details about the project:**

The learning rate of the perceptron is set to **0.1**.
It is trained on a bunch of randomly trained points(100 randomly generated points).
It's purpose is to figure out whether the x - coordinate of the point is greater than the y - coordinate if the point.
It uses the "sign" activation function.

```
    # activation function, return 1 if positive else -1 
    def sig(self, n):
        return 1 if n == abs(n) else -1
```

The training process looks like this,

```
    # training the perceptron with the training data
    for point in train_data:
        neuron.train(point.inputs, point.label)
```

The training method is defined as,

```
    # training the perceptron with known data
    def train(self, train_data, target):
        prediction = self.predict(train_data)
        error = prediction - target

        # nudging the weights by calculating delta weight
        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            delta_weight = error * train_data[i] * self.learning_rate
            self.weights[i] += delta_weight
```

Link to github repo: https://github.com/cipherDOT/perceptron

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: There are some problems in the implementation of the algorithm. The perceptron should iterate the data set repeatedly (unordered) until all the prediction results are correct in a certain iteration, but you only iterate once and do not confirm whether all the predictions are correct.

Comment: That is precisely what I would expect if you've got a sign error in your update rule. Do the math if you want to make sure and be careful about the sign and the order of the terms when calculating the error.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I wanna add that I was learning about perceptrons from the youtube channel "The Coding Train", [from this video](https://youtu.be/ntKn5TPHHAk?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aCibgK1PTWWu9by6XFdCfh&t=2176). I'll try your approach. Thank you again...

Comment: Update: It is still predicting only True or only False for all input data...

Comment: Update 2: IT WORKS! The problem was the way I was calculating the error/difference between the actual and the predicted value. As given above, I was using
```
error = prediction - target
```
when it should have been,
```
error = target - prediction
```

Due to incorrect error evaluation, my perceptron was giving me biased results. Now it's fixed. Thanks for helping me out!